# How to send custom response from service activator?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have inbound-gateway that except URL with 2 parameters. For testing just send in browser localhost://my-path/{param1}/{param2}. In serviceActivatorClass I accept these two params and after validation I want a browser to accept response like 200 OK, 404 not found (if something is not found), 409 conflicts, 500 Internal Server Error depending on my validation of these parameters. But I can't find a way how to send these errors that are standard for browser.

According to specification inbound-gateway should send 200 OK by default but I can't get it as well.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="myId"
                              request-channel="requestChanel"
                              supported-methods="GET"
                              path="/my-path/{param1}/{param2}">
        <int-http:header name="param1" expression="#pathVariables.param1"/>
        <int-http:header name="param2" expression="#pathVariables.param2/>
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <int:channel id="requestChanel"/>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="requestChanel" ref="serviceActivatorClass"/>
```

How to make service activator to send to browser standard errors?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` header in the reply message.

Comment: I added for inbound-gateway reply-channel="requestChanel" because I want to get reply from service-activator. Then I made service activator return Message. I try to modify my current message like message.getHeaders().put(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); and I got There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Content-Type cannot contain wildcard type '*'

Comment: You can't se reply-channel to `requestChannel`; you don't need a reply channel, the framework will automatically send the reply from a service activator that doesn't have an `output-channel`. If you want an explicit reply-channel (which is also ok), it must be a different channel.

Comment: Thank you Gary. I was able to send String from service activator and now I just try to find how to create message with HttpStatus.

Comment: Just return a `Message<?>` from your service; you may need to add a `<header-filter/>` on the replyChannel path to remove any inbound headers that are not appropriate.